# NHibernate 3.2 mapping choices, relations and POV?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to learn NH (ver. 3.2) and am having problems understanding some of the mapping choices. Scott Findlater has posted his fully working skeleton for sexy Loquacious NH [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/a-fully-working-skeleton-for-sexy-loquacious-nh.aspx) and my questions about mapping(s) will be based in his sample.
Here is the domain model (pic not part of his sample but included here for clarity):

[image]

His category class looks like this:

```
public class Category : Entity
    {
        public Category()
        {
            Products = new List<Product>();
            SubCategories = new List<Category>();
        }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

and his mapping class like this:

```
class CategoryMap : ClassMapping<Category>
    {
        public CategoryMap()
        {
            // **************************************************
            // Mapping of Id here will take precedence over the 
            // global conventions configured in the ModelMapper.
            // **************************************************
            //Id(x => x.Id, map =>
            //{
            //    map.Column("Id");
            //    map.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
            //});

            Property(x => x.Name, m => m.Length(450));
            Property(x => x.Description, m => m.Length(2000));

            Set(x => x.SubCategories, set =>
                                          {
                                              set.Key(k => k.Column("ParentCategoryId"));
                                              set.Inverse(true);
                                          } ,
                                       ce => ce.OneToMany());

            ManyToOne(x => x.Parent, manyToOne =>
                                         {
                                             manyToOne.Column("ParentCategoryId");
                                             manyToOne.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
                                             manyToOne.NotNullable(false);
                                         });


            Set(x => x.Products, set =>
                                    {
                                        set.Key(key =>
                                        {
                                            key.Column("ProductId");
                                            key.ForeignKey("FK_Product_Category_ProductId");
                                        });
                                        set.Table("Product_Category");
                                    },
                                    ce => ce.ManyToMany(m => m.Column("CategoryId")));
        }
    }
```

Now, for the questions:

1) Why did he chose to map/model Parent property as ManyToOne relationship? Doesn't this suggest that Category can belong to more than one parent category, i.e. any given category (other than the root I suppose) can be spread out among many other parent categories? If so then this is not very clear from the model itself because to me the Parent (as I see it in the class definition) looks like a property of type Category and I'd map it like that. When would you chose approach in this solution v.s. mapping it as a simple property?

2) When I map files, who's (or which) perspective I should be looking from? Seems to me like this is from the inside of the class you are trying to map. So, in this case, when I'm trying map the Category class, I'm only concerned with mapping the "arrows" going out, right?

3) Person creating mapping files must have knowledge outside of what's clear just by looking at a class. Look at how Products property is mapped (ManyToMany relationship). From the class itself it's only clear that Category may belong to many Products but Category doesn't know that it may be contained in many Products. That fact is obvious for the Product class. Now that I've said that seems to me that when I create mapping file(s) I should be looking from the point of view of a class AND then a model.

4) Generally speaking: when do you use .Inverse(), .Cascade() and .Lazy()?

5) What are the differences between mapping using ModelMapper vs ConventionModelMapper? I haven't studied files included in the same project which use the latter method but I wanted to know if there is, other than a preference, an advantage in using one over another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Scott decided to establish an [Ordinary Association(many-to-one)](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) association between a Category and its Parent(another) Category. A many-to-one association gives you access to features such as Cascading and Fetch strategies that you will not find in a property mapping. For example, imagine you want to delete a parent and all its children. Cascades can help you out.
2. If you have an association, you must think about both sides of the association. For example, say you have a bidirectional one-to-many association between **'A'** and **'B'**, you need to pay attention as to which side manages the relationship. When you are writing a mapping for **'A'**, you think in terms of how **'A'** relates to be, and viceversa when mapping **'B'**.
3. Your point is a bit unclear to me. However, what you seem to be describing is basic OOP object relationships. A class may have property **'A'** that IS a relationship to object **'B'** and **'B'** in turn may relate to **'C'**. Just by looking at **'A'** it is impossible to tell that it is transitively related to **'C'**. There is nothing wrong with that.
4. [Read the documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html).

   4.1 Inverse: Defines which side of a bidirectional relationship manages the relationship.

   4.2 Cascade: Allows certain operations to cascade to children associations. (e.g. Deletes)

   4.3 Lazy: Defines the strategy to load collection. (Eagerly/Lazily)
5. The ConventionalModelMapper is built on top of the ModelMapper and provides convenience methods and default mapping conventions that make the mapping-by-conventions experience easier.

Comment: I guess then I have a problem detecting (when looking at a domain model) when association is bi/uni directional. How should I think about association(s) between, say Product and Category? By looking at the model I see two, one-to-many associations - Products have many Categories and Categories have many Products. Is that incorrect? Or should I think about it as one many-to-many association?

Answer (score 1):

- For **1.** It doesn't mean that each category has many one parent category, it means that many Categories may be expressed in the same parent Category and each Category can have a list of Sub categories. If it was expressed as one-to-one, it would mean that each category has only one category and I think that you didn't mean to do that.
- For **4.** `Inverse()` is used to specify the owner of the association, so you might use it in a one-to-many relation where a child entity is not the owner of the relation or the child entity will not be responsible of the relation and it will have no knowledge about the relation, so if it was set to true, NHibernate will not try to insert or update the properties defined by the join.
- `Cascade()` specifies the operations that will be cascaded from the parent entity to the associated entities.
- `lazy` for lazy loading the entities referenced by other entities.
- For 2. and 3. I can't understand your point and What do you mean, but I think When you are mapping an entity, Yes you should look from the perspective of the class you are mapping and the same thing for the other side of the relation when you are mapping, it look from it's perspective put in the same time you should consider the two sides of the relation.